# Moving controls onto a container in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I have a winform with some controls mostly buttons and textboxs.

Now I have to move theese controls onto a splitcontainer, how can i do this i Visual studio 2010. I have tried to cut and paste and it seemed to work fine, but all the event disapeared.

Do i really have to start from scratch?

Comment: select all controls drag and drop on split container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select them and drag them onto the container. I know that when using Copy & Paste the events are not assigned - all you need to do is reassign them. They should stay assigned when dragging the controls onto the container.

You can make sure the controls are actually assigned to the container by moving the container and verifying that all controls move along with it.

Comment: _all you need to do is reassign them_ Um, this may be a whole lot of work..

Answer (score 17):

Another way to manage this is to enable the document outline for the form. This can be found in **View >> Other Windows >> Document Outline**.

The using this you can simply drag and drop. This is a useful tool if the split container panel is too small or off screen etc.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was looking for. Straight up drag and drop did not work for me.

Comment: Shazam! I have used VS for years and never known about this.